# Right way to start VirtualBox with shared folders mounted

Tags: command-line, mount, virtualbox

Need of commandline to start VM with access to shared folder. Now if I run

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox --comment "win" --startvm "c252555c-bla-bla"
```

I get VM running but shared folders not mounted, and I have to go to VirtualBox GUI manager and manualy  re-select sharedfolders connections. unless the checkbox automount is checked. It has no effect in commandline launch mode.

Comment: Did you make the share "permanent" ?

Comment: yes. automount and permanent both checked

Answer (score 0):

Use the `VboxManage` command, instead of the `VirtualBox` command.